# How to filter in a measure and display a measure in different colors?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I have this Data for my Dashboard:

```
date        country Size    town    
01.02.2018  germany 5000    berlin  
02.02.2018  france  2000    paris   
03.02.2018  germany 25000   berlin  
04.02.2018  france  20050   paris
```

How can I make a measure by filtering to country germany and town berlin in one expression?

I tried that with this measure

```
 var total = ndx1.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.size;});
```

Is it possible to use filterExact in get a measure? I can't find a solution

I just want to make static measures without filtering through interactive clicking. If I get the solution by do it with exactFilter() I will do it with a seperate crossfilter dataset.

Question 2)

Make a calculation like:

```
var total = ndx1.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.size;});
```

I just want to say:

Give me the exact Size and display this red if >5000 and yellow if >6000

I can't make an if function in this part:

```
<div class="dc-chart" id="measure">    <b>Measure:</b> </div><br>
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: For static measures that never change regardless of the filter applied, I would recommend calculating them without Crossfilter using Array methods `filter` and `reduce`. Is there a reason that approach won't work?

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Do you happen to know how i can filter ower all dimensions? If i like to get a piechart of country and filter it with size and town?

Comment: Take a look at built-in array methods like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter